# Locking file on samba to prevent edit conflict?

Tags: samba, smb, shared-folders, cifs, lock

I am trying to setup a samba server following  these:

**[Advanced Disk Shares](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html)**

**[Samba-HOWTO-Collection](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/locking.html)**

The idea is to only allow one account, one collection opening a file at once.

If another connection tried to open the same file, samba denies.

I tried `locking=yes`, `locks=yes`, `oplocks=yes` and combinations, didn't work as expected.

Is this possible at all with Samba 3.x ?